# swift UIActivityIndicatorView while NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection, uiactivityindicatorview

I know how to animate the UIActivityIndicatorView
I know how to make a connection with `NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest`

But I don't know how to animate the UIActivityIndicatorView WHILE making a connection with `NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest`

Thanks

Comment: You might be interested in this class: https://github.com/goktugyil/CozyLoadingActivity

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't use `sendSynchronousRequest` from main thread (because it will block whatever thread you run it from). You could use `sendAsynchronousRequest`, or, given that `NSURLConnection` is deprecated, you should really use `NSURLSession`, and then your attempt to use `UIActivityIndicatorView` should work fine.

For example, in Swift 3:

```
let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .gray)
indicator.center = view.center
view.addSubview(indicator)
indicator.startAnimating()

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    defer {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            indicator.stopAnimating()
        }
    }

    // use `data`, `response`, and `error` here
}

// but not here, because the above runs asynchronously
```

Or, in Swift 2:

```
let indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .Gray)
indicator.center = view.center
view.addSubview(indicator)
indicator.startAnimating()

NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
    defer {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            indicator.stopAnimating()
        }
    }

    // use `data`, `response`, and `error` here
}

// but not here, because the above runs asynchronously
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Rob in the comment, as long as you use a `SynchronousRequest` it will block your UI-thread and you won't be able to animate anything. Chris does a good job at explaining the two modes of `NSURLConnection` in [this article](http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/) (though for Objective-C, but you will get the idea). Among other things he compares the two modes as

> **Async or Sync?**
>
> So should you perform an asynchronous request or use a synchronous one for your application? I find that in the large majority of times, I’m using the async request because otherwise the UI would be frozen while the synchronous request is doing its thing and that’s a big problem when the user is performing gestures or touches and the screen is unresponsive. Unless I’m firing off a request to do something really simple and quick like ping a server, I default to using the async pattern.

This summarizes your options better than I could state it. So you really should learn about the asynchronous variant in order to be able to do your animation.